# MySQL query REGEX

Tags: mysql, regex, select

I've been searching for this for a while. I have a MySQL table with the following fields:

```
Id  | Parent | Code  |  Name
1   |   0    | 1     |  bla
2   |   1    | 1.1   |  blabla
3   |   1    | 1.2   |  blable
4   |   3    | 1.2.1 |  blablebla
5   |   3    | 1.2.2 |  blableble
6   |   1    | 1.3   |  blabli
7   |   1    | 1.4   |  blablo
8   |   0    | 2     |  ble
9   |   0    | 3     |  bli
10  |   9    | 3.1   |  blibla
```

... and so on!

I want to delete (`ID 3`) and recursively rebuild the `CODE` field so that it continues to be in sequence. For this example I only need to select ids with Code equal to:
1.3*
1.4*

In other words:

1. (Any number greater than 2)

How can I do this?

So the final table ends up with

```
Id  | Parent | Code  |  Name
1   |   0    | 1     |  bla
2   |   1    | 1.1   |  blabla
6   |   1    | 1.2   |  blabli
7   |   1    | 1.3   |  blablo
8   |   0    | 2     |  ble
9   |   0    | 3     |  bli
10  |   9    | 3.1   |  blibla
```

For the recursive delete I'm using the on delete cascade all, as PARENT is an index to ID.
But I need to manually select all the 1.3 ... 1.* and their children and rewrite them to 1.2 ... 1.(*-1)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please clarify.  What I get from your question is that if you were to delete the line with ID = 3, then the line with ID = 4 would change its Code field to be "1.2", and the line with ID = 5 would change its Code field to be "1.2.1".  Is that right?  A couple of other examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the correct regular expression would be:

```
^1\.[3-9]
```

This will match 1.3, 1.4, 1.3.1, etc. but it won't match 1.10. If you'd also like to catch those cases as well, use this:

```
^1\.([3-9]|\d{2,})
```

Comment: I wanted it to be more dynamic, how can I do some thing like:
selecting 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.2.1, 1.2.2.2... what how can I custumize the regexp you provived!?

Answer (score 0):

This would be one way to do it:

1. Take version number:

   ```
   1.2
   ```
2. Strip off the last number and escape the periods:

   ```
   1\.
   ```
3. Calculate the character classes that match the next version:

   ```
   1\.1[0-9]{2,}|1\.2[0-9]+|1\.[3-9][0-9]*
   ```
4. Anchor the expression:

   ```
   ^(1\.1[0-9]{2,}|1\.2[0-9]+|1\.[3-9][0-9]*)(\.|$)
   ```

As you can see, the process isn't simple, but it's the most logical I can think of. You might want to consider finding ways to turn your codes into a single number.